# floated text above absolute positioned image

Tags: html, css, css-float, css-position

How can I put a floated text above an absolute positioned image? The property `z-index` does not seem to work here.

**Example:** ([jFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2jchnbpz/))

```css
.box {
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px
}
.text {
  float: left;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<div style='position:relative'>
  <span class='text'>Hello</span>
  <div class='box'>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: simple give z-index to -1 in box class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add `position: relative;` to your text's CSS.

Just as a side-note you'll need to keep the z-index properties you've put too.

Or alternatively (but I wouldn't suggest it), add `z-index: -1;` to the box, and remove z-index from the text.

Answer (score 1):

```css
.box {
    z-index: 2;
    background-color: red;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
}
.text {
    float: left;
    z-index: 999;
    color: #fff;
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div style='position:relative'>
  <span class='text'>Hello</span>
  <div class='box'>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Adam add  z-index: 999; and  position: relative; to text.

Answer (score 0):

Just adding `Position:Relative` will work out in your code:

```
 .box{
  z-index:1;
  background-color:red;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  height:200px;
  width:200px
}

.text{
    float:left;
    z-index: 2;
    color: black;
    position: relative;
    }
```